# iOS: Localization gone wrong

Tags: ios, localization

I'm starting to get confused..I've wanted to finally add my translation file for all strings to my app according to ray wenderlich's tutorial. But somehow now everything got messed up. I removed now every localization again, which deleted my strings file, the storyboard etc. And now I have no localization language set in the project settings and I've copied all files back from the trash.

But my localized string (NSLocalizedString(..)) somehow don't load..or load something else. I've changed some of them to check if my strings file in the project explorer is actually used but it still uses the old strings and I have no idea from where..I've checked the project folder and there aren't any other files.

How can I set up everything again that it works? How can I set the strings file it should use? And how should I set up then the localization, with or without base language?

Edit: And in the simulator I cannot get my app running..it's showing only a black screen. Whereas on my iphone it still works (if I use my iphone from Xcode).

I guess I've deleted all my languages in project settings and now I cannot add any localization anymore :-(

Comment: did you try a clean and clean build folder? and are you using git?

Comment: Did you delete the app and reinstall it on your simulator??

Comment: I don't know what git is? And I could try deleting the app in the simulator. I did it though on the iphone and the strings aren't updated either..it still gets from somewhere the old strings..

Comment: I got it running in the simulator again. But it still loads old strings etc. But from where?!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would try:

1. Check your project folder for any leftover .lproj folders / .strings file and delete
2. Clean / Build
3. Start localization from scratch following [SmoothLocalize](http://smoothlocalize.com/)'s [Tutorial](http://smoothlocalize.com/tutorial1.php)

This should delete all old files and create a new default localizable.strings, and then you can add more languages.